# Displaying Angle Symbol in HTML

Tags: html, internet-explorer

The HTML symbol for angle, ∠ (&ang;) does not work in IE 6 or 7. What are the other alternatives to display the symbol in Internet Explorer ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a solution that incorporates both [Jamie's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/709827/displaying-angle-symbol-in-html/709836#709836) and [Shoban's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/709827/displaying-angle-symbol-in-html/709838#709838) answers and adds some conditional comments:

```
<style type="text/css">
span.ang { display: inline; }
span.ang_ie { display: none; }
</style>
<!--[if IE]>
<style type="text/css">
span.ang { display: none; }
span.ang_ie { display: inline; font-family: Symbol; }
</style>
<![endif]-->

<span class="ang">&ang;</span><span class="ang_ie">&#208;</span>
```

The above works on Windows in IE6, 7 & 8, Firefox 2 & 3, Opera 9.6 and Google Chrome 1.

It does not work in Safari for Windows 3 or 4. Safari for Windows renders a square for `&ang;` (and `&#8736;`). If Safari for Windows support is required, you are going to have to combine JavaScript to detect IE and Safari with  [Jamie's replace with image solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/709827/displaying-angle-symbol-in-html/709836#709836).

Answer (score 4):

Try using this

```
&#8736;

<FONT FACE="Symbol">&#208;</FONT>
```

I have checked and it works in ie7 :). http://comers.citadel.edu/math_sym2005.htm

Answer (score 3):

Try surrounding the angle with a

```
<span class="ang">&ang;</span>
```

then, if the browser is IE, show an image of the angle there using CSS.

See this article on attaching images with css:
http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/Attach_icons_to_anything_with_CSS

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the problem from the other end, i.e. as a user who sees hollow squares for `&lang;` (but also `&lang;` and `&rang;`), I found a solution for IE7 (on Windows XP):

In the Internet Properties (Sorry, I have only a German version here, so I don't know if this is the correct name.), go to Fonts, and set the text font to *Arial Unicode MS* or *Lucida Sans Unicode*.

Strange enough, even if a page doesn't use that font, just the setting causes IE7 to correctly interpret those HTML named entities.

Edit: Lucida Sans Unicode doesn't work for all entities.  E.g., `&ang;` or `&#8617;` display ok but `&lang;` and `&rang;` not.